# Listview onclick is not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onlongclicklistener

listview OnItemClickListener is not working after handling the listview item OnLongClickListener. when i long press in listview item then lognpress and onitemclicked both are firing at same time.

### listview xml file

```
         <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/event_adapter_text_color"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
                </ListView>
```

### Custome Adapter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_dummy_image" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_date"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_calendar_bground"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_month_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_date_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_event_month_textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_day_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_event_date_textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_time_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_event_date"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_log"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_date"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_event_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_view_event_date"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/event_adapter_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_event_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_event_location"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

### Custom Adapter code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        mView = convertView;
        EventUtil eventUtil = mEventUtil.get(position);

        mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_event_adapter, null);

        TextView eventTitleView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_title);
        TextView eventDescView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_location);
        TextView eventDateView = (TextView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_view_event_price);

        // new ImageFeach().execute(mEventUtil.getEvent_Image_Url());

        eventTitleView.setText(eventUtil.getEvent_Title());

        // event title sorting
        eventTitleView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // Toast.makeText(mContext, "LongClick",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mEventUtil != null) {
                    Collections.sort(mEventUtil, new EventComparator());

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // event description sorting
        eventDescView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // Toast.makeText(mContext, "LongClick",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mEventUtil != null) {
                    Collections.sort(mEventUtil, new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(EventUtil event1, EventUtil event2) {

                            return event1.getEvent_location().compareTo(
                                    event2.getEvent_location());
                        }

                    });

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // event price sorting
        eventDateView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // Toast.makeText(mContext, "LongClick",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mEventUtil != null) {
                    Collections.sort(mEventUtil, new Comparator<EventUtil>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(EventUtil event1, EventUtil event2) {

                            return event1.getEvent_Price().compareTo(
                                    event2.getEvent_Price());
                        }

                    });
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Listview Activity code

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                    int position, long arg) {
}
}
```

Help me .. Thanks

Comment: Share also your java code.

Comment: Please use a context menu for listview items longclick http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

Comment: i have shared java code now

Comment: HAve you printed any line in log after onItelclick of listview?

Comment: no after onItemClick it will call the anothere Activity

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) :

```
onLongClick() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have consumed
the event and it should not be carried further. That is, return true to indicate 
that you have handled the event and it should stop here; return false if you have 
not handled it and/or the event should continue to any other on-click listeners.
```

You need to return false in your onLongClick so you can handle the click event in onClick as well.

Comment: i have tried but list view onclick is not working onLongprss working immediately onClick is trigating

Comment: i have tried both cases(false,true) even ListView OnItemClick is not working when i press List Item onLongClick , LongClick is trigred and immediately ListView OnItemClick also trigred ...

Answer (score 0):

on item click event use this code

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v;
TextView text = (TextView)rl.getChildeAt(index);
```